# Getting SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl not found error wso2 AS

Tags: soap, connection, wso2, factory, esb

I am using wso2 latest stable version 3.2.0 and made a web service AXIS2 Service Project with imports from `javax.xml.soap.*;`

When I deploy the webservise in the Application Server from WSO2 it is accepted with no errors. But when I access it with SOAPUI or through the web interface from the Application Server I get:

```
"Unable to create SOAP connection factory: Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl not found"
```

I tried to inject the external jars containing this class by passing them into:
`repository/components/extensions folder or repository/components/lib folder`

All with no success. Who can and will try to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Latest WSO2 Application server version is 5.2.1 . You can download it from http://wso2.com/products/application-server . Please try on that server.